# Compare Audio Files

Tags: audio, embedded, file-comparison

I want to set up  a test-system for an embedded board, so I can automatically test both the audio out and the audio in jacks (LO, LI, HP, MIC). So I thought of recording an audio-file (with a sinus, or something), which I play on the same board, loop the LO to LI and HP to MIC. So I can use `aplay` and `arecord`.

But now I have to compare the original with the recorded file. A simple `diff` wouldn't work, because of the loss and noise. So I have to use some kind of trick to compare it and allow some variation, but I don't know what.

So, how can I intelligently compare two audio files?

Comment: Highly related and even maybe duplicate: http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/257925/37538

Comment: This type question may be more suitable at [softwarerecs.se]

Comment: @lgeorget ah, yes, fair point.