# How to manually begin/end speech recognition with X11?

Tags: speech-recognition

Having found speech recognition software that works well (see [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/256138/is-there-any-decent-speech-recognition-software-for-linux)),

I'm still left with needing integration, in my case, an easy way to activate it.

The outcome I'm looking for is:

- Press a shortcut to begin dictation.
- Press a shortcut to end dictation.
- The result is typed out, as if I was typing it in from a keyboard.

---

This is something I could probably manage using shell scripts (manually control an audio recorder, then use `xdotool` to type out the result). However solutions might already be out there, so I'm asking this question.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up writing my own tool for this purpose.

It's called [nerd-dictation](https://github.com/ideasman42/nerd-dictation) it's *(based on the excellent VOSK-API)*.